# Covariant use of generic Lazy class in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, covariance, lazy-initialization

Assuming that this applies:

```
public class Cat : Animal { }
```

and assuming that I have a method:

```
public void Feed(Animal animal) { ... }
```

And I can call it this way:

```
var animal = new Cat();
Feed(animal);
```

How can I get this working when `Feed` is refactored to only support `Lazy<Animal>` as parameter? I'd like to pass in my `var lazyAnimal = new Lazy<Cat>();` somehow.

This obviously doesnt work:

```
var lazyAnimal = new Lazy<Cat>();
Feed(lazyAnimal);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you won't be able to use it exactly as is.  Probably the simplest refactor would be to have it accept a `Func<Animal>` instead of a `Lazy`.  Then you could pass in a lambda that fetches the value of a `Lazy`.  `Func` is covariant with respect to it's return type.

Answer (score 12):

You can't, basically - not directly, anyway. `Lazy<T>` is a class, so doesn't suppose generic variance.

You *could* create your own `ILazy<out T>` interface, implement it *using* `Lazy<T>`, and then make `Feed` take `ILazy<Animal>` instead. The implementation would be trivial.

Alternatively, you could make `Feed` generic:

```
public void Feed<T>(Lazy<T> animal) where T : Animal
```

Or Servy's suggestion of taking `Func<Animal>` would work too, and you could call it using a lambda expression for the `Lazy<T>`:

```
Feed(() => lazyAnimal.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks so far; I should have mentioned (I wanted to keep it simple) that that class is actually a constructor? :) It's more like... The `FeedMachine` which I can't make generic. I'd check the `Func` approach though.

Comment: @thomasjaworski.com: Not sure what you mean by "that class is actually a constructor" - do you mean that method? You could always write a static generic method which called a constructor...